# What is my C++ project type in Visual Studios 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to add a new project to the existing solution. But when I create a new project to add to the solution, it looks different from the other projects in the solution. How will I determine what is the type of the existing projects in the solution? I am currently using Visual Studios 2008, however I am not sure which version of Visual Studios was used to create the old projects.

Answer (score 0):

A Visual Studio project does not have a "type". It has different *configurations*, and each configuration is a huge *set of options*. By default, two configurations "Build" and "Release" are created for a project, but this is just a convention.

Try googling for "visual studio copy project configuration to other project", it will give you a few hints on how to copy a project's options to another project. A very quick'n'dirty solution I can think of from the top of my head is to copy the project files on disk and then use the solution's "Add > Existing Project..." option.